# Whatsapp only partially restored

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger

Phone got stolen and got a replacement today. Restored Whatsapp It had stuff going back 2 years, but it didn't have the last 7 weeks of chat, I checked the settings and it's supposed to backup everyday...Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Can't say for sure without having the old device but maybe it was not backed up to Google Drive? Even if it did, such problems have been widely reported. All I can suggest is uninstall and try restoring again

Answer (score 0):

If the backup went all the way till %100 but you didn't get the past 7 weeks, this would mean that WhatsApp wasn't backing up for the last 7 weeks.

Being that the phone is now lost, there is no way to know why this is so. The fact that Google drive backup setting is set to do it every day, doesn't mean that this is the setting you had on your old phone. Because, WhatsApp backups do a full backup on your messages and media, but not your WhatsApp settings.

So it's very possible that on your old phone the setting was changed 7 weeks ago by mistake. Also possible that Google drive wasn't making backups for another reason. No real way to find the reason without checking on the old phone.